# In Google Analytics why does the Event Label = (not set)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

In Google Analytics why does the Event Label = (not set)

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a Google Tag that passes data to Google Analytics as an event type including the label. 
[image]

When I view the data in GA the Value == (not set).
[image]

When viewing the tag in Google Tag Assistance or Observepoint there is no Event Label. 
[image]

When viewing the dataLayer object there is a value for eventLabel
[image]

How can the tag be changes so the label value is passed correctly? 
Any & all assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I notice that the `gaEventLabel` is a nested string. IDK if that would cause any strange behavior, but it might be something to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Nested strings should work correctly.

It seems that this dataLayer event should fire at 'event': 'gaTriggerEvent', but your tag fires on "All pages" trigger.

Try to fire it with "Custom event" trigger and set'gaTriggerEvent' as Event name.